# Uploading a url image to s3 aws

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to upload an image but i keep getting an error with the export of the secret and key `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`. here is what i've tried

first i require the aws dependencies.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='key'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='secret'
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';¨
```

Upload image function

```
function uploadImage(url, title) {

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

      var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'bucket'} } )
      var data = {Key: title + "-" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000), Body: body};
      s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);
          } else {
            console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
          }
      });

    }
  })


}
```

run the function

```
uploadImage("http:/imageUrl", "test");
```

Comment: Have you given real AWS KEY and AWS SECRET in your code?

Comment: yes real aws key, secret, bucket name and url. i just didnt wanna put it in here

Comment: The two `export` lines of code look like Bash script code you probably copied from somewhere into your NodeJS app. That's why you are getting errors on those lines, because that isn't NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export` is not a correct way to add an environmental variable in node.js.

You should either

```
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='key'
...
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

or, most likely, pass them to your script as

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='key'
node server.js
```

`export` is a reserved js word.

Comment: seem to work, but how come it just add random characters to s3 and not an image file?

Comment: Assuming you download a correct image from `url`, I'd suggested that s3 doesn't recognize your raw data as an image. Adding `ContentType` key to your `data` object with an appropriate value may help.